# DateTime JavaScript vs C#

Tags: c#, javascript

Regardless of many posts I've read the magic still in my code.
I have DateTime value in db ('2011-03-30 00:00:00.000') that I retrieve for asp.net/mvc page where some javascript needs to read it and compare. The magic in the following:

```
<% 
DateTime unixTimeOffset = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime testDate = new DateTime(2011,03,30,0,0,0,0);
%>
<%= (testDate - unixTimeOffset).TotalMilliseconds %>
...
```

Last string of the code gives me this value: 1301443200000
When I try to read it in JavaScript I have:

```
val myDate = new Date(1301443200000);
```

And myDate is Tue Mar 29 2011 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {} But not a March 30th as it should be.

I understand it provides date referencing to local time, GMT-4 but what is the solution to get it independent? 
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. The `myDate` variable holds the correct date since `Tue Mar 29 2011 20:00:00 GMT-0400` is the same point in time as `Wed Mar 30 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0000`. My guess is that you see the former since that is your computers time zone. Use  `myDate.toUTCString()` to see the date as UTC.

Answer (score 6):

**For C# Related Dates:**

You may want to consider using [DateTime.ToUniversalTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [.UTCNow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx), which will allow you to keep all days independent of time-zones.

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.UTCNow();
```

**For Javascript-Related Dates:**

Javascript features a [UTC Method](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0240__Date/DateUTC.htm) that should get you the Universal Time as well.

```
//Declaration
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(YYYY,MM,DD));

//Use
var newDate = date.toUTCString();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `new Date(Date.UTC(1301443200000))` returns `Invalid Date {}` in Firebug. That is not a valid argument. This is the signature: `Date.UTC(year, month[, date[, hrs[, min[, sec[, ms]]]]])`

Comment: @lwburk - Clearly confused declaration and use :) Thanks!

Comment: Note that I don't think the JavaScript solution helps much, because what is really needed is the `YYYY`, `MM`, and `DD`, so they're not available as *input*, they're desired as *output*.

Answer (score 2):

Get the timezone offset in the client and add that to the value from the server. Like this:

```
var serverOffset = 1301443200000;
var localOffset = myDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
var myDate = new Date(serverOffset + localOffset);
console.log(myDate); // Wed Mar 30 2011 00:00:00
```

Please note that `Tue Mar 29 2011 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` is the same point in time as your original date in UTC. This method creates a new date that represents a *new point in time*. However, if you're just trying to display the same date value, then this method does the trick.

Alternatively, you can use `Date`'s UTC methods to print your original date in UTC:

```
function pad(num) {
    return ("0" + num).slice(-2);
}

function formatDate(d) {
    return [d.getUTCFullYear(), 
            pad(d.getUTCMonth() + 1), 
            pad(d.getUTCDate())].join("-") + "T" + 
           [pad(d.getUTCHours()), 
            pad(d.getUTCMinutes()), 
            pad(d.getUTCSeconds())].join(":") + "Z";
}

formatDate(new Date(1301443200000));
```

Output:

```
"2011-03-30T00:00:00Z"
```